# Qwik-react calendar plugin '@aldabil/react-scheduler' showing but not functional: How to troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qwik, qwikjs

Qwik-react Scheduler not working.
I was trying to use the "@aldabil/react-scheduler" react plugin in my qwik app using qwik-react but I got this error. the calendar is showing but the functionality is not working like when I cliked the cell there's nothing happen there.

Error: Named export 'Scheduler' not found. The requested module '@aldabil/react-scheduler' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export

[image]

[image]

I was expecting to make the "@aldabil/react-scheduler" running in qwik-react application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the React component in this way to solve your issue.
This code works in dev and preview mode

```
/** @jsxImportSource react */

import { qwikify$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-react';
import AldabilReactScheduler, {Scheduler} from '@aldabil/react-scheduler';

export const MyScheduler = qwikify$(import.meta.env.DEV ? Scheduler: AldabilReactScheduler.Scheduler, { eagerness: 'hover' });
```

Comment: Hi @Giorgio Boa, thanks for the answer but I'm getting this error when I use your code.
***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Scheduler')***

Comment: I updated the snipped, now the code works in dev and preview mode too.